# Swift change Pitch and Speed of recorded audio

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have an app who's foundation is essentially based on https://blckbirds.com/post/voice-recorder-app-in-swiftui-1/.

It's Swift / XCode 12.5.1 and works great. I call the audio using `self.audioPlayer.startPlayback(audio: self.audioURL)` which plays the recording perfectly.

Now I want to add the ability for the user to adjust the pitch and speed of the recorded audio. It doesn't have to save the changes, just apply the changes while playing the file on the fly.

I found https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/media/how-to-control-the-pitch-and-speed-of-audio-using-avaudioengine which simplifies the process of applying pitch changes. I'm able to change the `startPlayback` above to

```
self.audioPlayer.speedControl.rate = 0.5

do {
   try self.audioPlayer.play(self.audioURL)
 }
  catch let error as NSError {
  print(error.localizedDescription)
   }
```

after adding HWS's code into the **AudioPlayer** class, which proves it's working, but it's not an implementation.. it breaks some of the other capabilities (like updating and using the stopPlayback function), which I think is due to switching between the `AVAudioPlayer` and the `AVAudioPlayerNode` I'm trying to figure out if I need to rewrite the **AudioPlayer.swift** from the blckbirds tutorial, or if there's a friendlier way to incorporate HWS's into the project.

For example, I suppose I could create a toggle that would use the `AVAudioPlayer` playback if no effects are being used, then if the toggle enables one of the effects, have it use `AVAudioPlayerNode` instead.. but that seems inefficient. I'd appreciate any thoughts here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was simpler than I had thought using `@AppStorage` and conditionals to integrate the desired player. Thanks!